# IPv6 default route

Tags: routing, ipv6

The IPv4 default route in CIDR notation is `0.0.0.0/0` translated to

IP: `0.0.0.0`

mask: `0.0.0.0`

For IPv6 the default route in CIDR is `::/0`. How is this transated ? Is it as below ?

IP: `::`

mask: `::`

Comment: Don't actually worry about the human-readable IP addresses. The packets and network devices actually use binary numbers for IP addresses, not what you see. For IPv4, it is a 32-bit binary number, and for IPv6, it is a 128-bit binary number. A mask for either is the same length as an address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default route has a mask length of 0, so it matches anything. The network address with zero length is actually empty, but usually 0 is used.

It's the same with IPv4 and IPv6, just the notation of the latter has changed - :: expands to as many :0000 as are required to get a 128 bit address, so :: by itself expands to 0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000.